# Declare "container" object from templated template class and variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-templates

I need to declare a class which could store different kind of containers. i.e. It would be nice if it could handle std::bitset and std::array.
However, these two classes need a different of template arguments...
Is it possible (and possibly, how) to use templated template classes and variadic templates to declare this kind of class?

Example (but wrong):

```
template<template <typename..., std::size_t> class Container,
         std::size_t N,
         typename... Args>
class Base_Class
{
    ...
    Container<Args..., N/2> container;
};
```

The compiler complains that *N/2* is not a type. Obviously, for both std::array and std::bitset I need the size to be the last template parameter... Is it possible to code this crazyness?

Thank you!

EDIT:
As far as I am concerned, the main problem is that variadic templates can only be expanded on the right, therefore the variadic parameter must be the last one. Anyone know if there are any plans to allow the following syntax in C++17?

```
template<typename... Args, typename T>
struct A
{};
```

Comment: It gives error with both g++ and clang (obviously with -std=c++11/14 parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anton's answer can be made somewhat less *container-specific* by using template template parameters for the speciliasations of `ResizedContainer`:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename Container>
    struct ResizedContainer;

    template<template<typename,std::size_t> class Container,
             typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct ResizedContainer<Container<T,N>> {
        using type = Container<T,N/2>;
    };

    template<template<std::size_t> class Container,
             std::size_t N>
    struct ResizedContainer<Container<N>> {
        using type = Container<N/2>;
    };
}

#include <array>
#include <bitset>

template<typename Container>
class Base_Class {
    typename detail::ResizedContainer<Container>::type container;
};

int main() {
    Base_Class<std::array<int,4>> a;
    Base_Class<std::bitset<5>> b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename Container>
    struct ResizedContainer;

    template<typename T, size_t N>
    struct ResizedContainer<std::array<T, N>> {
        using type = std::array<T, N/2>;
    };

    template<size_t N>
    struct ResizedContainer<std::bitset<N>> {
        using type = std::bitset<N/2>;
    };
}

template<typename Container>
class Base_Class {
    typename detail::ResizedContainer<Container>::type container;
};

int main() {
    Base_Class<std::array<int, 4>> a;
    Base_Class<std::bitset<5>> b;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good. Anyway, it is pretty container-specific. Any ideas to avoid template specialization and write down a complete generic template class?

Comment: @dodomorandi I think you can't. C++ syntax doesn't allow it.

Comment: @AntonSavin *C++ syntax doesn't allow it.* I suspect you're right, but can you 'prove' that?